# Extracting a Value From an XML File in C#

Tags: c#, xml

Can someone help me out with extracting the "Value Y" of 4.247 in this XML file. I've searched through previous threads but can't seem to apply them to this structure.

```
<Chart1>
    <Chart1_SeriesGroup_Collection>
        <Chart1_SeriesGroup Label="MP_Trend_Data\MP_Prog/MP_DAILY_FLOW">
            <Chart1_CategoryGroup_Collection>
                <Chart1_CategoryGroup Label="12/24/2017 1:58:19 AM">
                   <Value X="0001-01-01T10:30:00+10:30"/>
               </Chart1_CategoryGroup>
               <Chart1_CategoryGroup Label="12/24/2017 1:58:19 AM">
                   <Value X="0001-01-01T10:30:00+10:30"/>
               </Chart1_CategoryGroup>
               <Chart1_CategoryGroup Label="12/24/2017 1:59:19 AM">
                   <Value X="0001-01-01T10:30:00+10:30"/>
               </Chart1_CategoryGroup>
               <Chart1_CategoryGroup Label="12/24/2017 1:59:19 AM">
                   <Value X="0001-01-01T10:30:00+10:30"/>
               </Chart1_CategoryGroup>
               <Chart1_CategoryGroup Label="12/24/2017 1:58:19 AM">
                   <Value Y="4.24700021743774" X="2017-12-24T12:28:19.333+10:30"/>
               </Chart1_CategoryGroup>
```

code I've tried:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load("C:\\attachment\\Flow.xml");

        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.LoadXml(xDoc.ToString());

        XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/Chart1/Chart1_SeriesGroup_Collection/Chart1_SeriesGroup[@Label='MP_Trend_Data\\MP_Prog/MP_DAILY_FLOW']");

        foreach (XmlNode Node in xnList)
        {
            XmlNodeList ynList = Node.SelectNodes("/Chart1_CategoryGroup_Collection/Chart1_CategoryGroup/Value");
            foreach (XmlNode Node2 in ynList)
            {
                textBox1.Text = Node2.Attributes["Y"].Value.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Comment: What have you tried ? Your code ? Errors ? We can't just write for you!

Comment: This is not a free coding service. You need to try for yourself and ask a question when your code does not work. Please read [ask].

Comment: I've tried this:  

var node = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("//*[@label='MP_Trend_Data\\MP_Prog/MP_DAILY_FLOW']");

to try and extract the node but it's returning a null value

Comment: @Chris edit your question to include details. Do not comment question specifics

Comment: Please post a complete and valid XML example.

Answer (score 0):

```
var xmlStr = @"
    <Chart1>
        <Chart1_SeriesGroup_Collection>
            <Chart1_SeriesGroup Label='MP_Trend_Data\MP_Prog/MP_DAILY_FLOW'>
                <Chart1_CategoryGroup_Collection>
                    <Chart1_CategoryGroup Label='12/24/2017 1:58:19 AM'>
                        <Value X='0001-01-01T10:30:00+10:30'/>
                    </Chart1_CategoryGroup>
                    <Chart1_CategoryGroup Label='12/24/2017 1:58:19 AM'>
                        <Value X='0001-01-01T10:30:00+10:30'/>
                    </Chart1_CategoryGroup>
                    <Chart1_CategoryGroup Label='12/24/2017 1:59:19 AM'>
                        <Value X='0001-01-01T10:30:00+10:30'/>
                    </Chart1_CategoryGroup>
                    <Chart1_CategoryGroup Label='12/24/2017 1:59:19 AM'>
                        <Value X='0001-01-01T10:30:00+10:30'/>
                    </Chart1_CategoryGroup>
                    <Chart1_CategoryGroup Label='12/24/2017 1:58:19 AM'>
                        <Value Y='4.24700021743774' X='2017-12-24T12:28:19.333+10:30'/>
                    </Chart1_CategoryGroup>
                </Chart1_CategoryGroup_Collection>>
           </Chart1_SeriesGroup>
        </Chart1_SeriesGroup_Collection>
    </Chart1>";

var xml = XElement.Parse(xmlStr);
var firstY = xml.Descendants("Value").FirstOrDefault(v => v.Attribute("Y") != null);
if (firstY != null)
{
    var y = firstY.Attribute("Y").Value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks JohnyL. How do I get my xml file into a string format as above?

Comment: @Chris -Pardon?

Answer (score 0):

Try xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            var results = doc.Descendants("Chart1_CategoryGroup").Where(x => x.Element("Value").Attribute("Y") != null).Select(x => new {
                label = (DateTime)x.Attribute("Label"),
                y = (double)x.Element("Value").Attribute("Y"),
                x = (DateTime)x.Element("Value").Attribute("X")
            }).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```